# Where can I find all of the alien artifacts in Fortnite?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

In Fortnite's Battle Royal, we're currently in Chapter 2 Season 7 which is alien themed. There is an additional resource available this season called alien artifacts that are specifically meant for unlocking customizations for the Kymera character:

[image: Kymera charcater customization screen.]

So far I've collected *174* of *360* alien artifacts and I'm trying to locate the rest. With that in mind, I know there are maps giving a week by week breakdown of artifact locations:

| Weeks 1, 4, 7, & 10 | Weeks 2, 5, & 8 | Weeks 3, 6, & 9 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image: Week 1] | [image: Week 2] | [image: Week 3] |
| [image: Week 4] | [image: Week 5] | [image: Week 6] |
| [image: Week 7] | [image: Week 8] | [image: Week 9] |
| [image: Week 10] |  |  |

However, looking at them individually does not quickly provide me with the following information:

- Which POI has the densest concentration of artifacts?
- If I drop in at the aforementioned POI, which POI should I travel towards in order to find the most artifacts possible in a single match?

---

Is there a single map image that can show all alien artifact locations?

Comment: The title of this question is to improve search results for future readers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: Screenshot of the map with alien artifact locations across various weeks marked.]

***Note**: If anyone would like to update this map at any time; the brush is a solid brush with 100% hardness and a size of 15px, the color utilized is `ff3434`.*

---

##### Where should I drop-in?

Based on density and accounting for elevation changes, you should drop-in at Slurpy Swamp. More specifically, you should drop in to the southwest of Slurpy Swamp:

[image: Screenshot of the recommended drop spot.]

##### Which direction should I travel?

To get the best bang for your buck, you'll start at the aforementioned drop spot and travel in an S shape to Corny Complex:

[image: Screenshot of the recommended path.]

While you'll initially miss out on the two central containers, you'll net approximately, *40* artifacts (assuming you haven't already gathered any in this path).

##### Where should I look?

After searching the web, I came across [an article](https://www.pcgamesn.com/fortnite/alien-artifacts-locations) that describes the locations of many artifacts.

##### Weeping Woods, Believer Beach and Corny Complex

The first points of interest on your list (assuming that you've already collected *some* artifacts) should likely be Weeping Woods, Believer Beach and Corny Complex. This is due to the fact that all three locations have five artifacts each in their surrounding areas:

| Point of Interest | Location Descriptions |
| --- | --- |
| Weeping Woods | inside a wooden shack that’s close to the Durrr burger west of Weeping Woods |
| - | close to the wall on the southern side, inside the smaller of the two wooden lodges with a blue roof |
| - | on the satellite dish at the IO station to the east |
| - | inside the small hut at the base of the guardian tower |
| - | to the southeast by a trio of trees just south of the main road and due north of Hydro 16 |
| Believer Beach | at the bottom of the Spire stairs east of Believer Beach |
| - | on top of the satellite dish in the IO base west of this location |
| - | inside the roof of the blue and brown house towards the southeast corner of Believer Beach |
| - | in the attic above the bedroom of the blue house, in the southeast of Believer Beach |
| - | inside the small hut on the crescent-shaped island to the west |
| Corny Complex | in the orchard to the north of Corny Complex, across the road |
| - | at the entrance to the bridge due south of this location |
| - | inside the barn furthest west in Corny Complex. Look to the ceiling to find it |
| - | in the corrupted area on the cliff overlooking Corny Complex (to the northwest) |
| - | inside the main dining hall of the Gas 'n' Grub |

##### Misty Meadows

Misty Meadows is the next likely location to result in a high yield for those who've already begun collecting artifacts.

| Point of Interest | Location Descriptions |
| --- | --- |
| Misty Meadows | on the left island due north of this location, in the house close to the spire |
| - | above the bell right at the top of the clock tower |
| - | underneath a small wooden bridge to the east |
| - | inside a blue shipping container at the IO station to the southeast |

##### Pleasant Park, Craggy Cliffs, Catty Corner and Slurpy Swamp

Each of these locations have a total of three artifacts in their immediately surrounding areas.

| Point of Interest | Location Descriptions |
| --- | --- |
| Pleasant Park | behind the house northeast of this location, close to the spire |
| - | under the roof of the wooden gazebo in the centre of Pleasant Park |
| - | underneath the roof of the gazebo in the centre of Pleasant Park |
| Craggy Cliffs | east of this location |
| - | by the campsite northeast of Craggy Cliffs |
| - | inside the roof of the Unremarkable Shack on the island to the northwest |
| Catty Corner | up the scratching post to the west of this location |
| - | head up the stairs in the camp at the top of the mountain and head inside the building |
| - | by the small house at the weather station on the mountain |
| Slurpy Swamp | inside the factory |
| - | inside Hydro 16, suspended in the air in the main room |
| - | head for the wooden buildings and look at the stairs of the one furthest east |

##### Retail Row, Boney Burbs, Coral Castle, Lockie's Lighthouse and Dirty Docks

These locations are a bit more spread out and are less likely to result in a high yield match. Each of these POIs have two artifacts.

| Point of Interest | Location Descriptions |
| --- | --- |
| Retail Row | by the pool close to the pylon northeast of this location |
| - | behind the bus stop by the road leading south of Retail Row |
| Boney Burbs | around the main complex in this location |
| - | in the corrupted area near the lake |
| Coral Castle | inside the castle in the centre of this location |
| - | inside the elevator shaft of the ruined base to the north |
| Lockie’s Lighthouse | inside the smaller shack next to the lighthouse |
| - | inside the shed next to the house. Lockie Lighthouse is on the island northeast of Coral Castle |
| Dirty Docks | next to where the alien trees are growing (the purple bit on the map between Dirty Docks and Steamy Stacks) |
| - | underneath one of the metal structures to the northwest of the IO base (west of Dirty Docks) |

##### Additional Locations

Of all the locations you could travel to, these will produce the lowest yields (individually, at least), in that they each only have one artifact to find. These are best utilized as fillers during the match once you've already hit the larger areas.

| Point of Interest | Location Descriptions |
| --- | --- |
| Steamy Stacks | on the pipes by the central building close to the floodlights |
| Isla Nublada | go to the island that’s just southwest off the coast between Slurpy Swamp and Misty Meadows. You’ll find the artifact inside the ruins |
| Holly Hatchery | inside the orange beach hut on the beach |
| Stealthy Stronghold | inside the left tower on the southern main gate |
| FN Radio | inside the IO base main building on the ground floor |
| Gorgeous Gorge | in the room with the suspended ships, it’s underneath the middle one. You’ll need to build a platform leading up to it |
| Camp Cod | on the small island southeast of Misty Meadows, head for the silver building to the east. It’s in the rafters close to the targets |
| Dampy Dish | the IO base southwest of Slurpy Swamp. It’s in a toilet cubicle |
| Zero Point | at the base of the new crater in the middle of the map |

Comment: @TimmyJim cleaning up the comments as we go, does that look a little better? If it still looks less clear with dashes, I'll swap them for the actual names :) just need a yay or nay. Also, going to remove this comment within 5 minutes of my next update or your response, whichever happens last.

Comment: I would have still used one Table with all the dashes replaced. But don't let me intrude, if you think it's good like this, then roll with it.

Comment: The table format wasn't intuitive to me. I would probably have preferred having one row per point of interest, with the right cell containing a list of locations.